# Regex Capture first slug in the URL don't capture if it have more that one slug/path

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture the first slug in the URL **only** if the URL has one slug, and ignore if it has more than one slug or section in the URL. For example:

```
https://example.com/path/some-slug-with-numbers-int ✅

example.com/path/some-slug-with-numbers-int/ ✅

example.com/path/some-slug-with-numbers-int/external/slug ❌ // ignore and don't capture
```

Trailing slash and no HTTP protocol is allowed.

My regex: https://regex101.com/r/0JYHMM/1/

```php
preg_match('/example\.com\/path\/(.*?)(\/|$)(?!\w)/', $input, $match);

if (!empty($match)) {
    $slug = $match[1];
    // $slug == 'some-slug-with-numbers-int'
}
```

It should capture the first and second URLs I posted, but my regex captures all  of them.

Comment: Unrelated to current issue but you can change your delimiter to an unused to character to avoid having to escape every usage of that char in the regex. e.g. `preg_match('~example\.com/path/(.*?)(/|$)(?!\w)~'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture everything that doesn't include a slash, and allow it only to have an optional trailing slash before the end of the string.

**Regex**

```
/example\.com\/path\/([^\/]+)\/?$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/K75aDD/1

---

Edit: As *user3783243* mentioned, it's generally easier to use a different delimiter for your regex if it's related to paths with lots of slashes, so you don't have to escape them all. Convention is often to use a hash `#` or tilde `~` in these situations.

```
#example\.com/path/([^/]+)/?$#
```